# Cutting audio and adding overlay in single command FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

How to add overlay and cut audio from a particular time in any type of video?

Here is what I am trying

```
ffmpeg -ss 5 -t 30 -i Happier.mp4 -i Watermark.png-filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,5,30)'" -preset ultrafast -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy output.mp4
```

Comment: Do you wish to mute the audio?

Comment: @Gyan Yeah Mute would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i Happier.mp4 -i Watermark.png \
       -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,5,30)'[v]; \
                        [0]volume=0:enable='between(t,5,30)'[a]" \
       -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -preset ultrafast -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
```